# Trying to get the current_user's latest email from a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Storing the current_user in a string after they submit a comment

```
<%= f.text_field :commenter, :value => current_user, :readonly => "readonly" %>
```

So i can get the email in my comment view

```
<td><%= comment.commenter.email %></td>
```

but i'm getting

```
undefined method `email' for "#<User:0x7f26828>":String
```

Anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to store whole object in html input? That shouldn't work, because you strore only string `#<User:0x7f26828>`. You should use relation between model:

```
class Commenter < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :commenter
end
```

In form:

```
<%= f.text_field :commenter_id, :value => current_user.id, :readonly => "readonly" %>
```

And add `commenter_id` column to `Comment` model. Then when you create just set `commenter_id` and everything should work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used attr_accessible in your User model?

```
attr_accessible :email
```

Comment: In error I see that class `String` has no method `email`. `#<User:0x7f26828>` isn't a object of class `User`, this is just string.